# Is it possible to transfer an Xbox Live account to another email?

Tags: xbox-network

10+ years ago I used to play a lot of Xbox 360. I'd hoped to continue using the same Xbox Live account again now on the Xbox Series X. Unfortunately however, the Hotmail address I used back then has somehow been taken over by someone else.

Is there any mechanism to move an Xbox Live account to another email address? If so, I'll try to convince the new owner of the Hotmail address to help me do that.

I've searched both Google and the Xbox support site and haven't come up with a decisive answer, so any help would be greatly appreciated.